# Чем height отличается от line-height?

Tags: css

Что-то я не пойму, чем именно отличается `height` от `line-height` в CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы раз и навсегда уяснить это для себя, возьмите следующий код:

```
<!--1--><div style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid;">Чуток текста в диве<br /> для демонстрации</div>
<!--2--><div style="line-height: 100px; border: 1px solid;">Чуток текста в диве<br /> для демонстрации</div>
```

Первое выведет прямоугольник высотой ~100px(примерно, так как я не обнулял отступы), в котором вверху будет наш текст.
Второе - прямоугольник высотой ~200px, так как две строки текста растянут блок на сумму своих высот. Кроме того, текст будет отцентрирован по высоте относительно верха и низа строки. Это удобно использовать для создания кнопок, чтобы не мучиться с padding и margin.

Comment: Вот тоже для понимания пригодится:
style="line-height: 75px; border: 1px solid; font-size:100px;"

Comment: неа, CSS тут жестко коцается. =(

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. В комментах не дает хтмл вставлять.

Comment: Дает. Но многие стили режет.

<table>
<tr><th>та</th><th>бл</th></tr>
<tr><td>ич</td><td>ка</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: Я имею ввиду сырцы показать типа <pre> или <code>

Comment: Для показа сырцов тут есть... барабанная дробь... ЧЕТЫРЕ ПРОБЕЛА!!! 
Перед каждой строкой, которая должна являться кодом. Кроме того, восле строки надо поставить два пробела, а до и после блока - по пустой строке. Но ничего,

    //По началу он непривычен, но потом - очень удобен.

Вот я все жду этого светлого мига....

Comment: Ой, спасибо! Очень полезно! Надеюсь это в факе есть, правда я его всё равно не читал О_о

Comment: По началу он непривычен, но потом - очень удобен +100500<br>
Правда я юзаю `<pre><code>` восновном ;)

Answer (score 3):

height - высота блока

line-height - высота строки

Comment: Если требуется пояснение, спрашивайте. Если нет, то не забывайте закрывать поврос ;)

Comment: спосибо за пояснение

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забывайте закрывать вопрос.

Comment: как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: @Рома Прогер Нажать на галочку слева от лучшего ответа.

Comment: На том ответе, который больше понравился кружочек с птичкой ;) под квадратиком с кулачком вниз